# Scriptella and (mysql) Stored Procedures "OUT" Parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, scriptella

I'm new to scriptella and have found it to be very useful thus far but have hit the following roadblock.  I have an SQL procedure that already exists within a MYSQL database similar to the following.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE FOO(IN input_param INT, OUT output_param1 INT, OUT output_param2 INT)
BEGIN
      /* real FOO sets output_params (conditionally) based on input_param */
      /*     AND updates an internal table */
      SET output_param1 = 1;
      SET output_param2 = 2;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I would like to invoke/call this procedure from within Scriptella, similar to the following:

```
    <query connection-id="in">
      SELECT SomeColumn FROM SomeTable;
      <query connection-id="out1">
          CALL FOO(SomeColumn, @OUT1, @OUT2);   // ERROR1 exception from this line, see below
          <script connection-id="jexl">
              etl.globals['OUT1'] = @OUT1;      // ERROR2 doesn't like "@"
              etl.globals['OUT2'] = @OUT2;
          </script>
      </query>
      <query connection-id="out2">
          INSERT INTO AnotherTable (col1, col2) 
                VALUES (${etl.globals['OUT1']}, ${etl.globals['OUT2']});
      </query>
    </query>
```

ERROR1 - Scriptella expects the line "CALL FOO(SomeColumn, @OUT1, @OUT2);" to return a resultSet.
Driver exception: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
** If I add "SELECT 1" to the end of the SQL stored procedure, it returns a value and eliminates this error.

ERROR2 - The code above attempts to store the OUT parameter(s) as temporary SQL variables, which don't work in Scriptella.
Driver exception: org.apache.commons.jexl2.JexlException: scriptella.driver.jexl.JexlConnection.run@80 tokenization failed

** It doesn't like the @ symbols or use of temporary variables here.

**QUESTIONS**
Does Scriptella support invoking stored procedures and returning OUT parameters?  I've tried a number of workarounds/hacks for this but haven't made any progress to date.

Answer (score 0):

The following script worked for me on mysql:

```
<!--
Example of calling the following procedure:
CREATE PROCEDURE demoSp(IN inputParam VARCHAR(255),
                    INOUT inOutParam INT, OUT outParam VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE z INT;
    SET z = inOutParam + 1;
    SET inOutParam = z;
    SET outParam = 'Out param';

    SELECT inputParam;
   END
//
-->

<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
    <connection id="in" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test" user="root"/>
    <connection id="out" driver="text"/>

    <!-- Calling a stored procedure -->
    <script connection-id="in">
       CALL demoSp('abc3', @a, @b);
    </script>
    <!-- Using output parameters -->
    <query connection-id="in">
        select @a,@b;
        <script connection-id="out">
            $1,$2
        </script>
    </query>
    <!-- Calling a stored procedure and iterating resultset (if any) -->
    <query connection-id="in">
        CALL demoSp('abc3', @a, @b);
        <script connection-id="out">
            Row: $1
        </script>
    </query>
</etl>
```